# Table of Contents not symmetric with Tuftes symmetric option

Tags: table-of-contents, tufte

I'm using the tufte-latex class and was able to change the layout with

```
\documentclass[twoside,symmetric]{tufte-book}
```

Unfortunately the Table of contents is still not symmetric, but always left-aligned. Is it possible to change this?

Comment: There was no need to delete the other post ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yep that was a mistake

Comment: There is an `undelete` button, but since you've posted it again, it's no use to undelete the older one ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want? I used *small* values for the margins (;-)) and `showframe` package for comparison, checking...

Since `tufte-book` already loads `geometry` package, one can just say

`\geometry{lmargin=somevalue,rmargin=somevalue}`

where somevalue is the desired margin width, but in this case both values must be equal (for symmetry)

```
\documentclass[twoside,symmetric]{tufte-book}
\geometry{lmargin=4cm,rmargin=4cm}

\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\frontmatter
\chapter{First at front}
\blindtext
\mainmatter

\chapter{Other stuff}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes exactly, but unfortunately I'm not sure which of your commands are solving the problem here.

Comment: `\geometry{lmargin=yourvalue,rmargin=yourvalue}`

Comment: This changes to layout of my complete document (and my TOC looks now really strange). Is it possible to make the changes only for the TOC?

Comment: I thought it should be for the whole document? Please clearify your question. And use `\newgeometry{...}` as in the preamble but before `\tableofcontents` and then again (with other values) **after** `\tableofcontents`