# How to specify B5 in tufte-book

Tags: tufte

I'm having trouble creating a working b5 layout with tufte-book. According to their documentation, this is supported:

> The Tufte-LATEX classes currently only provide three paper sizes:
>   a4, b5, and us letter.

I'm however confused because nowhere it says how we're supposed to change it to b5. I tried `\documentclass[b5paper]{tufte-book}` but the result has visual flaws (e.g. the title is clipped at the sides, so is chapter numbering, etc.) - it seems like it's the wrong way to do it. Also, the documentation says the `b5paper` option is unsupported:

> The tufte-book class is based on the LATEX book document class.
>   Therefore, you can pass any of the typical book options. There are
>   a few options that are specific to the tufte-book document class,
>   however.
>
> The a4paper option will set the paper size to a4 instead of the
>   default us letter size.
>
> The following book class options are unsupported: 10pt, 11pt,
>   12pt, a5paper, **b5paper**, [...]

So - What's the correct way to change it to a working b5 layout?

Comment: Hi and welcome, you can use package `geometry` to set the paper size. But you might need reset the margin stuff.

Comment: It's not a duplicate of this question, but the geometry change from here should work too: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/237704/table-of-contents-not-symmetric-with-tuftes-symmetric-option

Comment: The code is there to support it. Can you please provide a small example document which we can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the problems you're seeing?

Comment: Using the `b5paper` option is the “proper” way to do it. The note in the document about it being unsupported is a bug: I added the `b5paper` option later and forgot to remote it from the list of unsupported options. If you're having trouble with the `b5paper` option, please provide an example so we can help rectify that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The `b5paper` option seems to work fine. Here the `showframe` facility from `geometry` (which the class loads) is used to illustrate:

[image: B5 layout]

```
\documentclass[b5paper]{tufte-book}
\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\geometry{showframe}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle
  \chapter{A chapter}
  \kant[1-5]
  \section{A section}
  \kant[6-7]
  \chapter{Another chapter}
  \kant[8-12]
\end{document}
```